# Pass records to a dialog

Tags: axapta, x++

In a customised form I would have a create Purchase Menubutton which opens a dialog to create a purchase order.

But I need to select few records like one or two lines and then create purchase order only for those records. How do I do that?

Comment: What are the records you select? Sales lines? What are the relations between you lines and a purchase order?

Comment: we have a customised module where they have something called tools which contains items in it. We will be creating purchase requistion for those

Comment: Look at my answer. I think it will help you a lot. If you want I can provide you with the steps you have to follow to complete your task. One question: Do you work in MS Dynamics AX 2009 or 2012??

Comment: i work in AX 2009.. yes please provide me the steps

Comment: Tejashree S-> Please mark your questions answered if somebody correctly answers them.  You've asked several questions that have been answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the "Create purchase order" button on the `SalesTable` form.

It works differently: you select the lines to purchase after you press the button, but it might work in your case also.

Also have a look on [how to use multiple selected records](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Multiple_grid_selections) in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code which allows you to get the record from the previous form.

You have to put this piece of code in the INIT method of the dialog. So you have to override the init of the dialog.

```
DmoVehicleTable       vehicleTable;
DmoVehicleId          vehId;

// Get the vehicle ID from the previous form
if (element.args() && element.args().record())
{
    switch (element.args().record().TableId)
    {
        case (tableNum(DmoVehicleTable)):
            vehicleTable     = element.args().record();
            vehId            = vehicleTable.VehicleId;
            break;
        default:
            throw error (strFmt("@SYS477", this.name()));
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

If you need more help: http://sirprogrammer.blogspot.com/